# How to implement multiple custom cells with willDisplayCell method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to implement two custom cells, **customCellView1** and **customCellView2** in the willDisplayCell method - which seems only to support one cell. Is there a way to rewrite this to include two? 
Thank you.

- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell: (**customCellView1** *)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Answer (score 2):

It all lies ultimately in your `dequeue` call in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You get to specify the reuse identifier. So if this row needs a type 1 cell, you give the reuse identifier for type 1, but if this row needs a type 2 cell, you give the reuse identifier for type 2. And you branch according to which one it is.

Well, the reuse identifier is attached to the cell. So now when you get to `willDisplayCell:`, the same thing is true: you cast as a `UITableViewCell*` to start with, but then check the cell's reuse identifier and branch according to which type it is.

Comment: However, I would rethink your strategy here. Implementing `willDisplayCell` is almost never necessary. You should be able to do _all_ the work in `cellForRow`.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the class of the cell in an if/else.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([cell is kindOfClass:[CustomCellClass1 class]] ) {
       [(CustomCellClass1 *)cell doWhatever];
    }
    else if ([cell is kindOfClass:[CustomCellClass2 class]] ) {
       [(CustomCellClass2 *)cell doSomethingDifferent];
    }
}
```